# How to update shopping cart QTY

Tags: php, database, shopping-cart

I am making a shopping cart lie this pic I attached

[image]

The sum of the product is depent on the buyer
my question is how can I press update button to update all QTY of  the product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use Javascript to update the form itself.

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    $(".update_button").click( function() {
        //update the quantities here.
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, btw how to get the value from all the input tag of the qty?

Comment: var quantity = $(".quantity_input").val()

Comment: With the code u given cannot get all the value right?
can it save to the database also?

Comment: you have to go through all of the input tags during the click event to do exactly what you want to do.